# Django Tastypie Deserializing Multipart/Form-Data To Upload File

Tags: django, tastypie

I am trying to upload files via a Multipart/Form-Data form and Tastypie API and am running into some issues:

My Model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    client_image = models.FileField(upload_to=client_image_path, default="/assets/img/default-user-image.png", blank=True, null=True)
    client_image_thumb = models.FileField(upload_to=client_image_thumb_path, default="/assets/img/default-user-image.png", blank=True, null=True)
```

I am using a custom deserialize method as outlined in Tastypie Issue#42:

```
class MultipartResource(object):
    def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
        if not format:
            format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')

        if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            return request.POST

        if format.startswith('multipart'):
            data = request.POST.copy()
            data.update(request.FILES)
            return data

        return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

    def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE').startswith('multipart') and \
                not hasattr(request, '_body'):
            request._body = ''

        return super(MultipartResource, self).put_detail(request, **kwargs)
```

And here is my corresponding ModelResource:

```
class ClientResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
    account = fields.ForeignKey(AccountResource, 'account')

    class Meta():
        queryset = Client.objects.all()
        always_return_data = True
        resource_name = 'account/clients/client-info'
        authorization = AccountLevelAuthorization()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get','post','put','delete','patch']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete','patch']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }
```

If I do a POST with content-type application/JSON and dont include the client_image field, it will successfully create a new Client Object.  This indicates that the models/resources are working as they should.

However, when I try to use a Multipart/Form-Data content type I can see that it gets through my deserializer appropriately with this payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryp0Q7Q9djlsvVGwbb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{%0D%0A%22account%22"

"/api/v1/account/account-info/21/",

------WebKitFormBoundaryp0Q7Q9djlsvVGwbb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_image"; filename="donavan.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryp0Q7Q9djlsvVGwbb--
```

I am also seeing this QueryDict while debugging, which shows the InMemoryUploadedFile correctly:

```
<QueryDict: {u'client_image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: donavan.jpg (image/jpeg)>], u'{%0D%0A%22account%22': [u'"/api/v1/account/account-info/21/"']}>
```

but I keep getting this error:

> { error_message: "" traceback: "Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py",
>   line 202, in wrapper response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py",
>   line 440, in dispatch_list return self.dispatch('list', request,
>   **kwargs) File "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py",
>   line 472, in dispatch response = method(request, **kwargs) File
>   "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py",
>   line 1328, in post_list updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle,
>   **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs)) File "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py",
>   line 2104, in obj_create bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle) File
>   "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py",
>   line 890, in full_hydrate value = field_object.hydrate(bundle) File
>   "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py",
>   line 732, in hydrate value = super(ToOneField, self).hydrate(bundle)
>   File
>   "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py",
>   line 165, in hydrate elif self.attribute and getattr(bundle.obj,
>   self.attribute, None): File
>   "/Users/stevewirig/Documents/www/vu/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py",
>   line 343, in **get** raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist DoesNotExist
>   " }

Any ideas where this could be broken? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I post a data without providing necessary fields. Those fields that cannot be null must be provided while posting.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the serializer as follows:

`serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])`